# Are there markings on studs or drywall that indicate when it was made?

Tags: drywall, studs

I am trying to figure out when a wall was installed. I am certain it was not original to the house since the wood color does not match many of the other studs and there are left overs of an older wall behind this one.

Are there markings on studs or drywall that could indicate when it was made?

Comment: You could check with the local building department. If a permit was pulled for the work, they should have it on file.

Comment: Well, I am not sure that they would have pulled a permit as I suspect the work may have done to cover up a defect...

Comment: To determine the age of the studs, just count the tree rings...

Comment: (That was humor.)

Comment: I don't know about other countries, but in the US, you can figure out when in the century the studs are from, based on their dimensions.  (between ~1906 and ~1924, 2x4s shrunk to roughly 1.75x3.75 after drying;  In the late 1950s/early 1960s it went down to 1.5x3.5.).  If you look at other boards (nominal 1" thick, 2x6, 2x8) it might be possible to get a more specific decade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes there is a date of manufacture printed on the backside of drywall. Old ink on brown paper may be hard to see.

The modern stuff is not infrequently dated to the second, presumably for quality control, as it spews off the line.

[image: Picture from "lemurzone" showing a date code on the back-side.]

Answer (score 2):

Not generally though it might depend on the manufacture.  There might also be a lot code which the manufacture could associate to a date.  If there is a window in the wood then usually the manufacture date is stamped inside the window.

But just because the studs are different colours doesn't necessarily mean they are older or newer.  Most dimensional lumber is known as SPF - Spruce, Pine, Fir.  So when you go buy lumber, you might get any one of these three types of wood.  If you buy different lumber at different lumber yards on the same day, you will get different looking wood.

Comment: I am certain it is NOT original though. The original outside walls were all hung with faring strips, not studs. Additionally, I found the original wall behind it.