# Dating insulation or studs for determining when prior work was completed

Tags: insulation

Thanks in advance for any help. My wife and I purchased a house two years ago and have finally gotten around to remodeling the bathroom. When pulling down the old drywall we were surprised to see significant termite damage to the studs and top plate of a load bearing wall. Someone had sistered several studs and blocking to some of the damaged areas. The work is substandard. The previous owners did not disclose this damage and owned the house for 15 years prior to us. We were wondering if there was any way to date the mfg date of the insulation or studs so that we could see if they did or did not have prior knowledge of the work. Thanks,

Shawn in New Orleans

Comment: My mill has stamps that identify the mill name & grade I don’t remember if they have a date code if they do it would probably only be a year I will look tomorrow.

Comment: How old is the house reputed to be and did you save any drywall, for drywall has date stamps on the sheets, at least in recent times. The stamp will be on the back, if it is there

Comment: You might want to check this out.

https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/67182/are-there-markings-on-studs-or-drywall-that-indicate-when-it-was-made

Comment: You may check with your local building authority if they pulled a permit for any of the work.

Answer (score 1):

Not for the lumber may have a grade stamp on it that does have various information but there is no date. The insulation might have a manufacturing date on it, it is worth checking. However, to my knowledge it is not at all required.